# Efficient algorithms for checking if a binary-tree is a subtree of another binary-tree

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree, pattern-matching, binary-tree

Given two *binary-trees* T1 and T2, is there any efficient algorithm to check if T1 is a *subtree* of T2? The binary-trees are *ordered* and *labeled*, i.e., every node has a label and the left/right child cannot be swapped.

For example, T1: [image] is a subtree of T2: [image]

The naive algorithm runs in O(|T1| * |T2|) by simply going over every node of T2 and checking if T1 could be matched at that node.

Is O(|T1| + |T2|) possible?

Comment: You might get a better answer over at the Computer Science stackexchange site: http://cs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

The subtree (C, (D), (B)) consists of two upward links, D-(L)>C and B-(R)>C, where L and R distinguish left from right links. Any subtree with n leaves consists of n upward sequences, each starting at a leaf and ending at the root of the subtree, with the sequence recording both the letters of the nodes and the left or right nature of the links it moves up on.

Build an http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_string_matching_algorithm string-matcher to recognise these sequences, and run it on the paths of the larger tree that start at its leaves and end at its root.

When an Aho-Corasick match is found, mark the match and which sort of match it is on the highest node of the sequence that matched it. If you find a node of the larger tree that accumulates a collection of one each of the patterns that you built into the Aho-Corasick matcher, this node is the root of a copy of the smaller subtree you were trying to find.

Comment: I suppose this method is also O(|T1| * |T2|)?

Comment: Constructing an Aho-Corasick tree of size n is O(n). Checking n characters of text against this tree is O(n + number of matches found). In most cases I would expect it to be O(|T1| + |T2|) in practice. There might be a few degenerate cases to be careful about - if the larger tree is very tall with few leaves you will be repeating yourself if you search all the way up from all the leaves - you might note down the state of the Aho-Corasick matcher as you go and break off if you are in the same state at the same place as before.

Answer (score 0):

There is an algorithm of O(kT1+T2), first traverse T2 find all nodes whose value equals T1's root value, suppose we've got k such nodes, this traverse of T2 takes O(T2). Then for each of these nodes, check if it is a match of T1, this takes O(kT1). If T2 is unique or there is only one node equals T1's root, the complexity is exactly O(T1+T2). The code to find T1's root node in T2 is like this:

```
void do_find_nodes(node* root, T value, std::vector<node *>& nodes)
{
    if(root)
    {
        if(root->val == value)
            nodes.push_back(root);
        do_find_nodes(root->left);
        do_find_nodes(root->right);
    }
}
void find_nodes(node *root, T value)
{
    std::vector<node *> nodes;
    do_find_nodes(root, value, nodes);
}
```

Calling find_nodes() will give you all nodes in T2 whose value equals T1's root, then you can check if each node is a match of T1.